# SAXParseException: premature end of file

Tags: android, saxparser

I have an XML file hosted on my Google drive. It has some data that is needed for my Android app to run. So, I decided to test if I could get the data from the file and made a test `SAXParser`. However, I get a `SAXParseException`:

```
org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 1; columnNumber: 1; Premature end of file.
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.createSAXParseException(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.fatalError(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLScanner.reportFatalError(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl$PrologDriver.next(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl.next(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanDocument(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XMLParser.parse(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.parse(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.SAXParserImpl$JAXPSAXParser.parse(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.SAXParserImpl.parse(Unknown Source)
    at testing.TestSAX.processFeed(TestSAX.java:54)
    at testing.TestSAX.main(TestSAX.java:40)
```

Although, this same code works properly for, say RSS feeds, it crashes for the Google drive file.
Here is how I open the stream:

```
try{
            SAXParserFactory factory = SAXParserFactory.newInstance();
            SAXParser parser = factory.newSAXParser();

            InputStream stream = new URL(url).openStream();
            Reader r = new InputStreamReader(stream,"UTF-8");
            InputSource source = new InputSource(stream);
            source.setEncoding("UTF-8");

            parser.parse(source, this);
        }catch(Exception e){
            errorOccured = true;
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

**How do I solve this?**

Comment: http://developer.android.com/training/basics/network-ops/xml.html. use xmlpullparser instead of sax. quoting from docs "recommend XmlPullParser, which is an efficient and maintainable way to parse XML on Android."

Comment: Probably you are getting empty string in response due to this you are getting EOF

Comment: @HarishGodara Is there a way to solve it ?

Comment: most likely, the server stopped delivering the file mid-way.

Comment: What is your URL and how does the xml file look like?

Comment: @Terry Hi, again !! The XML file has a set of `CDATA` section that have links from where I fetch information. The link is proper as it opens perfectly in browser :)

Comment: Can you post the link?

Answer (score 0):

There is some problem with your InputStream please read this carefully : `http://www.danielschneller.com/2008/01/saxparseexception-1-1-premature-end-of.html`

Comment: *sigh* It fails only for the Google Drive url. It works fine with RSS feeds so I am assuming that Google does not allow hosting XML files